# How to generate SSH keys inside yubikey?

Tags: authentication, ssh, digital-signature, yubikey

How do I generate SSH keys inside my yubikey, on Ubuntu?

There seems to be nowhere to look for this info.

Comment: See https://developers.yubico.com/SSH/

Comment: @mti2935 this is for generating the keys on the computer and then sending to yubikey

Comment: Can you generate keys *on the Yubikey* in any method?

Comment: Further, what is the threat vector which precludes you from following the linked procedure?  Generate it, send it to yubikey and then securely delete it.  This would only be unacceptable if the resource generating the key is not completely in your control.

Comment: @foreverska firmware malwares could mess with the kernel's random number generator

Comment: Boy, what an attack vector.  The private key to an ed25519 key is any given random number.  Rolling a 32 sided die gives you a nice 6bits of information per roll, you need 256.  I'd start rolling because I can't find reference that it's possible to generate keys inside a yubikey.

Comment: I'll ask again... "Can you generate keys on the Yubikey in any method?" You ask about doing it on Ubuntu, but does the OS matter? Does the device even have this functionality? I'm thinking that this isn't a security question but a product support question. This sounds like a "does this product have this function?" question. Have you asked Yubikey?

Comment: @schroeder I used a yubikey, sent my own private key, used for ssh, 2fa, etc. And the OS matters because usually you need some driver to interact with the yubikey and tell it to generate the key. I think this fits this forum because it's a question about usage of something basic on authentication and there's nothing on the web about it

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand what you wrote, but it does not appear to answer my question. But "usage of something basic on authentication" is not what this is. You want to know how to get this device to do something specific. That's a product support question.

Answer (score 3):

I asked the question verbatim on reddit r/yubikey and got the following answer, along with another with some reference to gpg.

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -O resident # resident means, that the key will be generated on the yubikey
It produce the following output:

user@pc:~$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -O resident
Generating public/private ed25519-sk key pair.
You may need to touch your authenticator to authorize key generation.
Enter PIN for authenticator:
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk.pub
The key fingerprint is: SHA256:ztpJ8rTSlo07BQ0LyL6hI2X9/CE9fTdy0EQZhAnxc74 user@pc
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/yubikey/comments/tzfgas/generating_key_inside_yubikey/

Comment: `Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk):` wouldn't it generate in the local OS?

Comment: If you have a reddit account, the person in that thread seems to be very knowledgeable.  BUT, '-o resident' was explained as the option which forces the yubikey to generate the key on device.  Instead of passing back the private key it seems to pass back a "handle" to the key on the device.  Per this thread:
https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/hzxdbf/what_does_sk_stand_for_in_ecdsask_and_ed25519sk/

Answer (score -1):

Type the following commands on the command line:

```
gpg --edit-card
admin
generate
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Could you explain what do the different commands do, and how this answer could complement or correct already existing answers.